# Using CSS to position div's held in a parent div and the content below it

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to use css to position two `div`'s, one directly above the other. This usually works fine except the height of the `div` on top has a dynamic height as content is added or taken away using javascript. Inside of that `div` I have a series of other `div`'s but the parent `div` does not expand to cover the ones inside of it. I need a way to make the `div` on top expand in size to cover every child it has.

And help or alternate solutions would be awesome.

Comment: please create a fiddle with current css and html [Here](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: How can we suggest "alternate" solutions without seeing your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by having floated elements inside of your div. You can either add a clearing div at the end of its contents with style `clear:both;` or add `overflow:hidden;` to the dynamic height div

This is explained in detail on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Thankyou for this, it worked beautifully with the clear:both in the css.